# Where are all the Debian ISOs?

Tags: linux, debian, distributions, iso

I am downloading ISOs for the "wheezy" distribution of Debian Linux for an old AMD box without any Internet. However, the index at http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.1.0/i386/iso-cd/ only lists the first 8 CDs while the MD5SUMS file has hashes for over 70 ISO images. So where are the rest of the ISOs? Is there an alternative site to FTP these?

Comment: You usually need only the first CDs/DVDs for a desktop install; the last ISOs only have the oddball package that very seldom is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Debian CD FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#not-all-images):

> **Some Images are missing! Only the first n images are available! Where is the rest?**
>
> We don't store/serve the full set of ISO images for all architectures, to reduce the amount of space taken up on the mirrors. You can [use the jigdo tool](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#why-jigdo) to recreate the missing ISO images instead.

Don't feel bad about not finding the FAQ. I had to hop on IRC and ask the `dpkg` bot.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to this URL on the Debian website, http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/, you'll find what you're looking for. The links to the various architectures are available towards the bottom of the page.

Here' are the main 2 you're probably looking for:

- [i386 Debian 7.1.0 DVD ISO](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.1.0/i386/iso-dvd/)
- [amd64 Debian 7.1.0 DVD ISO](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.1.0/amd64/iso-dvd/)

The above page is [also available from the Debian page](http://www.debian.org/CD/). In general it's best to use [bittorrent](http://www.debian.org/CD/torrent-cd/) or [jigdo](http://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/) to download these large ISOs.

Comment: Both those links are similar to the one I gave in my Q. Not all of the images are included for dl.

Comment: @MonadNewb - yes and if you read the entire answer I also suggested to use bittorrent or jigdo. Those are the best options for downloading the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all .iso images for all architectures [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/).

Comment: Did I mention that this computer is *not* connected to the Internet? I am looking for the *all* the ISOs for the distribution, not just the net-install one.